# Is there a command to make the code reset to a certain line? (Python)

Tags: python

I'm nearly finished with a project I've been working on, it is a hangman game. I've been trying to add a feature where you can restart the game after you finish and pick a new difficulty. It works, sorta, but whenever you select a difficulty that has already been selected, it kills the program. I was wondering if there was a command that will allow me to reset the program to a certain line somewhere in the beginning of the code.

[Full Code Here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1l4E_tlAVNvmyzLmc2pvZEHo3kUS1ihqkYUx1vbw5wuc/edit?usp=sharing)

Problem areab(for reference purposes):

```
  if lives == 0:
    print("           ")
    print("-Im sorry, " + playername + ", it seems that you cannot make any more mistakes.")
    print("-The answer was '" + letter1 + letter2 + letter3 + letter4 + "'.")
    print("-Better luck next time.")
    print("                           ")
    playagain = str(input("Would you like to play again, " + playername + "? "))
    while True:
        if playagain in (accept, reject):
            break
        print("                           ")
        print("-I'm sorry, " + playername + ", I do not understand your answer . . .")
        print("                           ")
        playagain = str(input("Would you like to play again, " + playername + "? "))
        print("                           ")

    if playagain == accept:
         lives = 6
         from random import randint
         num = randint(1,10)
         true1 = False
         true2 = False
         true3 = False
         true4 = False
         difficulty = str(input("Choose a difficulty, easy, medium or hard. "))
         break

    if playagain == reject:
         print("⢀⢀⢀⢀⢀⢀⢀⢀⢀⢀⢀⢀⢀⢀⢀⢀⢀⢀⢀⢀⢀⢀⢀⢀⢀")
         print("Thank you for playing!")
         print("This game was coded by *developer name*")
         break
```

Answer (score 0):

Python does not have a `goto` or equivalent command.